# Where does Lynx store its cookies?

Tags: cookies, ubuntu-12.04, lynx

I was wondering where does lynx the text based web browser stores its cookies. Having a look at the manual there are options on how to enable cookies, etc. but couldn't find a way to have lynx delete the stored cookies. Therefore I might have to delete them manually but not sure where they are located!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx):

> ```
> -cookie_file=FILENAME
> ```
>
> specifies a file to use to read cookies. If none is specified, the default value is ~/.lynx_cookies for most systems, but ~/cookies for MS-DOS.

Answer (score 6):

if you press the `?` you can see the help, if you want to see a list of stored cookies press 
`CTRL-K`